# The phalcon app failed when running the codeception tests

Tags: php, automation, phalcon, functional-testing, codeception

According to the instructions, he created a bootstrap phalcon-project, added it to the modules
I run the code `codecept run functional -d`
At start of functional tests there is an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class phpMorphy_Exception, because the name is already in use in /home/hyber/test/backend/library/library/Service/phpmorphy/src/common.php on line 35

`functional.suite.yml:`

```
actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
enabled:
    - Phalcon:                       
        bootstrap: 'config/bootstrap.php'
        cleanup: true
        savepoints: true
    - Asserts
    # add a framework module here
    - \Helper\Functional
```

`config/bootstrap.php:`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);


try {

    $config = include __DIR__ . "/config.php";
    include __DIR__ . "/loader.php";
    $di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();
    include __DIR__ . "/services.php";

    return new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);


} catch (\Phalcon\Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

} catch (PDOException $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

help me please!

Answer (score 0):

phpMorphy_Exception is getting declared twice maybe in both the test bootstrapping and the frameworks.

Comment: Thank you! this is already written in error, but why this is happening, it is not clear